# Simple CSS with .TXT include

Tags: html, css

I am using a .TXT Include on these pages.

The background was BLACK before I implemented the include, now it is WHITE. Still all works though, can't figure that one out

Please Visit the Link Below and **Click** the RED BAR.
http://careersinmusic.com/index.aspx

It should load a Modal Window, but the frame is white, but it WAS black JUST BEFORE I added the post-title.txt include.

Thanks Much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What include do you mean? It's white at the moment due to line 31 of `css/colorbox-book-previews.css`:

```
#cboxContent{background-color:#FFF;}
```

If you want it to be black, just remove this line.